# Google Chart not accepting my data - claims column may not be string

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Google Chart doesn't accept my data - although I really tried hard to build it exactly the same way the example is built.

This is the example from Google that works in my code:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
     'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
    ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
    ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
  ]);
```

And this is my array:

```
0: (7) ["Warengruppe", "Ausstattung", "Baby-Mode Sets", "Babypflege", "Personalisierte Schuhe", "Spielzeug", {…}]
1: (7) ["2018_12", 2972, 43812, 16435, 15480, 18608, ""]
2: (7) ["2019_01", 3527, 41577, 16124, 18132, 17128, ""]
3: (7) ["2019_02", 3671, 33655, 13151, 19623, 13478, ""]
4: (7) ["2019_03", 5931, 44647, 17372, 23101, 21126, ""]
5: (7) ["2019_04", 8737, 40356, 18562, 24440, 23018, ""]
6: (7) ["2019_05", 11400, 44798, 14150, 34773, 26308, ""]
```

Why is it not accepting this array. Always get the message "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"

Answer (score 0):

data seems to work fine here,
is there more code that might affect the outcome?

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = [
    ["Warengruppe", "Ausstattung", "Baby-Mode Sets", "Babypflege", "Personalisierte Schuhe", "Spielzeug", {role: 'annotation'}],
    ["2018_12", 2972, 43812, 16435, 15480, 18608, ""],
    ["2019_01", 3527, 41577, 16124, 18132, 17128, ""],
    ["2019_02", 3671, 33655, 13151, 19623, 13478, ""],
    ["2019_03", 5931, 44647, 17372, 23101, 21126, ""],
    ["2019_04", 8737, 40356, 18562, 24440, 23018, ""],
    ["2019_05", 11400, 44798, 14150, 34773, 26308, ""]
  ];
  var dataChart = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataChart);
});
```

```html
<script src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<div id='chart_div'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right - those arrays seem to work. I did actually produce those arrays by an Ajax-Call and put them together in Javascript - and this seems to break the order of things. But I solved my problem in the meantime and avoided Google Charts by building the chart manually (quite some work but took me less time than searching for the bug in my JS ...) - Thanks again. Problem solved.